# Using ng-repeat/ng-option select expression in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

ng-repeat and ng-select allow the user to pass in an expression in the style select X as X.Name. I'm wondering if it's possible to use this style of expression in a custom directive.

I've had a look through the angular source for ng-options and repeat, but I've not been able to find exactly how they evaluate these attributes. If someone could point me to an example or the documentation that would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The use case is for an angular typeahead component, I wish to be able to pass in  both arrays of primitives and objects, change how their displayed as well as what is actually assigned to the ng-model. It is also for my own knowledge should this ever become a requirement for use in work.

Comment: They use quite complex regexp: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L218 and for ngReteat too https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L337

Comment: @dfsq cheers for the link, now I have two problems! :)

Comment: Will you tell us what you are trying to do? I doubt you have to use strings when passing data to a directive

Comment: @DonJuwe I've added the usecase to the original question. I can try to be more clear if needs be

Comment: @Scott Then create your own directive and pass those arrays?